# Camera rotation and OrbitControls in react-three/fiber

Tags: three.js, camera, react-three-fiber

I am trying to create a scene with `react-three/fiber` and `react-three/drei`. I want to use a PerspectiveCamera and be able to **pan/zoom/rotate with the mouse**, but I am also trying to add some buttons that can update the camera position and target in order to have different views (eg. top view, bottom view, side view, etc). I have achieved the latter part and my buttons seem to be working as I update the target **x,y,z** and position **x,y,z** using props.

The only problem is that the camera is not responding to the mouse so I only get a fixed camera position and target.

I have included all the scene codes below.

```
import React,{ useRef, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import * as THREE from 'three';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PerspectiveCamera, Icosahedron, OrbitControls } from '@react-three/drei'

import { Canvas, useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";

function VisualizationComponent(props) {
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  const [controls, setControls] = useState(null);
  const [threeState, setThreeState] = useState(null);
  const [treeStateInitialized, setThreeStateInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    if(threeState){
      _.forOwn(props.objects, (value, key) => {
        threeState.scene.current.add(value);
      });
    }

    return () => {
      if(controls) controls.dispose();
    }
  },[])

  function usePrevious(value) {
    const ref = useRef();
    useEffect(() => {
      ref.current = value;
    });
    return ref.current;
  }
  const { objects } = props
  const prevState = usePrevious({objects});
  const mainCamera = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!threeState) return;
    if (
      !treeStateInitialized ||
      shouldUpdateObjects(props.objects, prevState.objects)
    ) {
      setThreeStateInitialized(true);
      garbageCollectOldObjects();
      addDefaultObjects();
      _.forOwn(props.objects, (value, key) => {
        threeState.scene.add(value);
      });
    }

  })

  const addDefaultObjects = () =>  {
    if (threeState) {
      var hemiLight = new THREE.HemisphereLight( 0xffffbb, 0x080820, 0.2 );
            hemiLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
            threeState.scene.add( hemiLight );
    }
  }

  const garbageCollectOldObjects = () => {
    while (threeState && threeState.scene.children.length) {
      const oldObject = threeState.scene.children[0];
      oldObject.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.geometry) {
          child.geometry?.dispose();
          if(child.material && Array.isArray(child.material)){
            child.material.forEach(d => d.dispose());
          }else{
            child.material?.dispose();
          }
        }
      });
      threeState.scene.remove(oldObject);
    }
  }

  const shouldUpdateObjects = (currentObjects,nextObjects) => {
    const result = false;
    let currentDigest = 1;
    let nextDigest = 1;
    _.forIn(currentObjects, (value, key) => {
      currentDigest *= value.id;
    });
    _.forIn(nextObjects, (value, key) => {
      nextDigest *= value.id;
    });
    return currentDigest !== nextDigest;
  }

  const hasAncestorWhichDisablesThreeJs = (element) => {
    if (!element) return false;
    let isEditable = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < element.classList.length; i++) {
      if (element.classList[i] === 'disable-threejs-controls') {
        isEditable = true;
      }
    }
    return isEditable ||
      hasAncestorWhichDisablesThreeJs(element.parentElement);
  }

  const initializeScene = (state) => {
    setThreeState(state);
    addDefaultObjects();
  }

  return (
    <div
      id="threejs-controllers-div"
      className='threejs-container'
      onMouseOver={ (e) => {
        const target = e.target;
        if (!target || !controls) return true;
        if (hasAncestorWhichDisablesThreeJs(target)) {
          controls.enabled = false;
        } else {
          controls.enabled = true;
        }
      } }
    >
      <Canvas
        className='threejs'
        onCreated={ (state) => {initializeScene(state)}}
        shadows={true}
        gl={
          {
          'shadowMap.enabled' : true,
          'alpha' : true
          }
        }
      >
        <PerspectiveCamera
          makeDefault
          ref={mainCamera}
          position-x={props.cameraX || 0}
          position-y={props.cameraY || -20}
          position-z={props.cameraZ || 20}
          up={[0, 0, 1]}
          fov={ 15 }
          aspect={ width / height }
          near={ 1 }
          far={ 10000 }
          visible={false}
          controls={controls}
        />
        <OrbitControls
          ref={controls}
          camera={mainCamera.current}
          domElement={document.getElementById("threejs-controllers-div")}
          enabled={true}
          enablePan={true}
          enableZoom={true}
          enableRotate={true}
          target-x={props.targetX || 0}
          target-y={props.targetY || 0}
          target-z={props.targetZ || 0}
        />
      </Canvas>
      <div className='threejs-react-container'>
        { props.children }
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

VisualizationComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
  objects: PropTypes.object.isRequired,

  cameraX: PropTypes.number,
  cameraY: PropTypes.number,
  cameraZ: PropTypes.number,
  targetX: PropTypes.number,
  targetY: PropTypes.number,
  targetZ: PropTypes.number,
};

export default withRouter(VisualizationComponent);
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://codeworkshop.dev/blog/2020-04-03-adding-orbit-controls-to-react-three-fiber/) it may help